# Reference material to understand Riemann zeta function

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Can anyone refer me a good material to read about Riemann zeta function? I am referring Riemann Zeta function by Alexander Ivic, which is a little complicated.

Comment: That's because Riemann Zeta function is a little complicated. The book is ok, imho, you can't explain that still simpler.

Comment: Yes, but maybe there are some more materials in which it is presented simply, that is what I am looking for

Comment: Titchmarsh book is the basic book and Ivic is the advanced book; Edwards gives a historical approach and could be useful as a gentler introduction and Patterson and Iwaniec have short books but are more limited; an alternative to Titchmarsh is Karatsuba and Voronin treatise and Karatsuba's short but useful volume about Complex Analysis in Number Theory

Comment: The material to recommend depends greatly on your knowledge of complex analysis (and related).  I recently published a book: [link]( https://www.amazon.com/dp/0996167137), intended to be useful for those who found even Edward’s book a bit too difficult.  Read the description at the link to see if it might be a good fit.  Also, to allow a preview, I had Amazon make 40% of the book viewable with their “Look Inside” feature (I can only test that in the US, but hopefully it is available elsewhere).  Moderator: if mentioning your own book is discouraged, delete this comment.